# How to transfer a generic map with other XMLElement in JAXB Class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have below User JAXB class. How to use JaxB class If I would like to use a generic Map and two "name" and "id" XmlElement in the JaxB class. 
So, user can use name, id xml elements and other generic attributes for example as below.

```
Example :
JSON Format 
{"name":"xyz","id":"1","xx":"axx","yy":"byy"}

OR 
XML Format 
<name>xyz</name>
<id>1</id>
<xx>axx</xx>
<yy>byy</yy>


@XmlRootElement
public class UserJaxB {

private String name;
private String id;

/* Generic Map */
private Map<Object, Object> map;

public UserJaxB() {
}

@XmlElement(name = "id")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Map getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap(Map<Object,Object> map) {
    this.map = map;
}
```

}

Comment: I think it's not a good idea, what if someone put "id" or "name" in the map? I would name the map "extras" and live with `{"name":"xyz","id":"1","extras":{"xx":"axx","yy":"byy"}}`

Comment: thanks for comment. But my requirement is {"name":"xyz","id":"1","extra1":"xx","extra2":"yy"} not nested. "extra3" and/or "extra4" could be added in above example

Comment: I would try with a class that `extends Map<String, Object>`